# data not writing to firestore database

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

The code below is a component within nextjs with the purpose of writing data to a firestore database after the user clicks a button.

Firebase isn't writing my data to the firestore database, however the alert within my callback (that is after the supposed datadump) works. i tried checking over my process.env file to see if that's where the problem was, but that wasn't the issue.

heres my write file

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const WriteToCloudFirestore = () => {

    const sendData = () => {
        try {
            //send data
            firebase
                .firestore()
                .collection('myCollection')
                .doc('my_document')
                .set({
                    string_data: 'string',
                    more_data: 123
                })
                .then(alert('data sent to firestore'))
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.log(e)
            alert(e)

        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={sendData}>send data to cloud firestore</button>
        </>
    )
}

export default WriteToCloudFirestore
```

if you are in need of anymore files I can add them, but as far as I'm aware firebase has been initalized on my app. I looked through some other questions on this forum and was able to find a very similar problem that had to do with the data returning null - but I don't see how that's my issue because I am placing data in my *.set* portion of the firestore code.

Comment: `.then(alert('data sent to firestore'))` This alerts *immediately*, then passes the return value from the alert into `.then`.

Comment: I've taken the .then(alert) away completely and the data still isn't being written to firestore

Comment: Just pointing out why you're getting an alert that looks like a success. Try adding a `.catch` to the promise chain and seeing what gets logged out in there. Your try/catch block can only catch synchronous errors, not async ones.

Comment: For example: try, `.set({ /* ... */ }).catch(err => console.log(err))`

Comment: yes and thank you for that bit of info, as i'm still developing my understanding of async code. so - very similar to this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54153085/firestore-not-writing-user-data-to-data-base i am not receiving an error at all.

Comment: If you change the code as Nicholas says, do you still get the alert? If not, can you edit your question to show the updated code - and update the description of what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Javascipt alerts are synchronous that means it'll block any code execution unless the alert is dismissed. The moment you dismiss the alert your data will pop up in Firestore. Therefore, you should handle the promise returned by Firestore set method first and then show the alert.

```
firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("myCollection")
      .doc("my_document")
      .set({
        string_data: "string",
        more_data: 123,
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Data addded")
        alert("data sent to firestore")
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

Alternatively you can use `async-await` syntax:

```
const sendData = async () => {
    console.log("Sending Data");
    try {
      await firestore.collection("myCollection").doc("my_document").set({
        string_data: "string",
        more_data: 123,
      })
      alert("Data added to Firestore")
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
}
```

You can read more about that behaviour in this [blog](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-do-javascript-alerts-without-being-a-jerk#:%7E:text=One%20of%20the%20nice%20things,execute%20until%20it%27s%20been%20dismissed).